# Weird browser colors in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, browser, colors, color-management

I have been running 18.04 for about 3 months and I started to see weird colors in the browser. Note the green/yellow/blue edge on the react symbols here [image: here]

Can anyone point out a reason for why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Which theme are you using? This might be due to custom themes.

Comment: @Kulfy I'm using the standard 18.04 theme

Comment: @Kulfy does it matter if I have i3 installed on the system?

Comment: by i3, you mean processor? No, it doesn't matter. Do you see similar behavior in Firefox?

Comment: By i3 I mean the tiling window manager https://i3wm.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After further investigating this issue I found out that the problem was with the Chrome browser.

In order to fix this you need to disable hardware acceleration.
**Chrome** -> **Settings** -> Uncheck **Use hardware acceleration when avaialable**.

Comment: Working for me, That's weird.

Answer (score 2):

In my case navigating to

`chrome://flags/`

and setting `Force color profile` flag to:

`sRGB linear (HRD where available)`

helped.

Comment: Mine works with hardware acceleration enabled, and forcing color profile to `sRGB` and not the linear option. Mine also works when hardware acceleration is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I've realized this is a problem with Chromium & Electron based applications picking the wrong color profile. While all solutions mentioned here solve the problem for Chrome, the solution I've found fixes it for all Chromium/Electron based applications, such as VSCode & Discord.

Go to this Google Docs document and follow the 5 steps under "Using colormgr from the command line". This fixed the issue on all Chromium-based applications.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jMokB_OBkZVELu22li8vnHxAUoL1eGnLedP-1Gttv40/edit#heading=h.z8rbug83238e

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Goto `chrome://flags/` 
**Step 2**: Change `Forced Colors` settings to enabled.

Solved!